# I'm reading "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" and there is something that I don't understand

Tags: c++, templates

It says:

> A function generated from a function template is never equivalent to an ordinary function even though they may have the same type and the same name. This has two important consequences for class members:
>
> - A constructor generated from a constructor template is never a default copy constructor.

Firstly, I don't understand how that conclusion came from the first statement.

Secondly, when I try to simulate that conclusion, it gives me an error that it cannot be overloaded, so I don't understand the outcome either.

Edit: the code I used

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class entity
{
 private:
 int x;

public:

entity();
entity (int const& y):x(y)
{
  printf("non-template");
}
entity (T const& y): x(y)
{

}

};
int main()
{
    entity<int> en(5);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the code that you're using "to simulate that conclusion", in order to illustrate your question?

Comment: I think you might be interpreted "equivalent" differntly. The shown code generated two identical constructors, hence the compilation error. The textbook was talking about a template-generated constructor never been equivalent to a copy constructor, this is something else entirely.

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to give the question a title that summarizes the *question you are asking*. Ideally, please also explicitly ask a question in the post, instead of just saying what it is that you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy constructor is a *non-template* constructor with a certain signature. A specialization of a constructor template is never (by definition) a copy constructor.

I think "*consequences*" is not really used here to mean a logical implication immediately following from the previous statement. I think it is rather just meant to demonstrate some examples where the differentiation between an ordinary function and a function specialized from a function template matters.

This use of the word "*consequence*" seems to be a linguistic oddity. I sometimes see it used like this. It really seems to mean something more like "*this allows for the following (and the following is true)*".

The point here is that only declaring a copy constructor (meaning a non-template constructor) can inhibit the declaration of the *implicit* copy constructor. So if you only declare a constructor template that can be specialized to have the same signature as a copy constructor, there will still be an implicit copy constructor.

I don't know though what the author means with "*default*" in "*default copy constructor*". I would usually guess they just used an informal variant for "*implicit*", but that wouldn't make sense in the context.

---

In your example code there is no constructor template. The declaration of a template begins with `template</*...*/>` (or since C++20 as a function with `auto` placeholders in parameter types).

```
entity (T const& y): x(y)
{

}
```

This is just an ordinary non-template constructor. It's parameter type does depend on the template parameter of the class, but that doesn't make it itself a template (although a *templated entity*). Even setting that aside, if you specialize the class for e.g. `entity<int>`, then the parameter becomes type `int const&`, not `entitiy<int> const&`, so it won't have the signature of a copy constructor at all. The compiler complains about impossible overload because there is already another constructor with exactly the same parameter list and both are non-template constructors.

A constructor template would be e.g.:

```
template<typename U>
entity (U const& y): x(y)
{

}
```

and this one would not inhibit the implicit declaration and definition of the implicit copy constructor although it can be specialized to `entity(entity<T> const&)` for `U = entity<T>`. Overload resolution will then still choose the implicit copy constructor instead of this constructor template to perform copies.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I did what you said and it gave me the exact behavior said in the book. what I got from your answer is that when the compiler generate an implicit copy constructor it will always be chosen over the template copy constructor  and there is no relationship between  this and the fact that there's no ordinary function equals to a template function

Comment: @stackoverflowuser No, as I explained a template (or a specialization thereof) cannot be a copy constructor in the first place (by definition). Whether the implicit copy constructor is chosen over a constructor template of the form I have shown is a matter of overload resolution and is not generally one way or the other. For example if you remove `const` on `U const&` there will be situations in which the constructor template overload will be preferred. The normal overload resolution rules apply.